# Map-like UI navigation on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit

I'm experimenting with a UI concept where my views are laid out like a net and the user can swipe in different directions to navigate through the app. Here's a very rough mockup:

[image]

I understand I can use UISwipeGestureRecognizers to trigger animations, but I'd really like to move the views WITH the user's finger as they swipe, like Clear for iPhone does when you swipe up or down, or like Readability & Reeder do when you swipe back.

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the example for handling touch events directly, especially UIResponder's touches moved : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html